# Is it dangerous to pass user input directly to strftime?

Tags: ruby, user-input, strftime

I have a form input that collects any arbitrary string. I'd like to pass that input directly to strftime such that users can specify their own formats. For example: `"mytext%Y"` might be input from a user which I would then pass to strftime.

```
# userinput = "mytext%Y"
mydate = DateTime.now.strftime(userinput)
# outputs "mytext2000"
```

Is this safe to do? If not, what would a developer need to consider or put in place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is safe.

The worst it can happen is when the user inputs an invalid format, it will simply print the string out.

```
Date.today.strftime('%A')
# => "Tuesday"

Date.today.strftime('#{1 + 1}')
# => "\#{1 + 1}"
```

Comment: Is there a time when something like this is unsafe, similar to SQL injection?

Comment: `strftime` is "safe" in that it doesn't execute any user-supplied data as code or causes any side-effects. However, depending on what you do with the resulting value, you might need to be careful since the resulting string can be any string value without any restriction (it can contain Null bytes, whitespace, SQL, HTML, Javascript or any other string value). Thus, you need to consider the returning value with the same care you would with other user-supplied data.